# How to combine polymer-redux and <app-route>?

Tags: polymer, redux, polymer-1.0

We are currently using `<app-route>` for routing, and are now implementing Redux using `polymer-redux`. It's unclear what the best way is to combine the two, however. Since `<app-route>` maintains its own state, we can't really store it in our Redux store. However, for some actions the user can perform, we also want to update the URL.

My current line of thinking is doing *something* with middleware, but it's not quite clear to me how best to access/modify the routes in `<app-route>` from within that middleware. How can we best approach this?

Answer (score 4):

I've ran into the same problem myself. The clash is that the main principle of redux is that it advocates for a unique *centralized* state, while polymer advocates for multiple *decentralized* states. Reconciling both obviously requires some hack from time to time. Syncing the browser URL in the redux state through polymer (to use with app-route) is a good example. Using [app-location](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/app-route/app-location), what I've done is this:

```html
<!-- my-app.html -->
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/app-route/app-location.html">
<link rel="import" href="/src/redux/redux-behavior.html">
<link rel="import" href="/src/redux/route-action-creator.html">

<dom-module id="my-app">
  <template>
    <app-location route="{{_browserRoute}}"></app-location>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-app',

      behaviors: [ReduxBehavior, RouteActionCreator],

      properties: {
        _browserRoute: {
          type: Object
        }
      },

      observers: [
        '_browserRouteChanged(_browserRoute.*)'
      ],

      _browserRouteChanged: function(browserRoute) {
        this.dispatch('browsed', browserRoute.base)
      }
    })
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

We use a two-way binding to keep my-app's _browserRoute in sync with the browser url. Upon change, it dispatches a 'browsed' action, which is going to reduce the current route in the state to the new value of _browserRoute.

```html
<!-- route-action-creator.html -->
<script>
  const ROUTE_ACTIONS = {}
  const routeActions = {}

  ROUTE_ACTIONS.BROWSED = 'ROUTE_BROWSED'
  routeActions.browsed = function(route) {
    return {
      type: ROUTE_ACTIONS.BROWSED,
      route: route
    }
  }

  ROUTE_ACTIONS.REDIRECTED = 'ROUTE_REDIRECTED'
  routeActions.redirected = function(path) {
    window.history.pushState({}, null, path)
    window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('location-changed'))
    return {
      type: ROUTE_ACTIONS.REDIRECTED,
      path: path
    }
  }

  /**
   * Route action creator behavior
   * @polymerBehavior
   */
  RouteActionCreator = {
    actions: routeActions
  }
</script>
```

```html
<!-- route-reducer.html -->
<link rel="import" href="/src/redux/route-action-creator.html">
<script>
  const reducers = {}
  reducers.routeReducer = function(state, action) {
    if (!state) {
      return {
        current: null
      }
    }

    switch (action.type) {
      case ROUTE_ACTIONS.BROWSED:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
          current: action.route
        })

      case ROUTE_ACTIONS.REDIRECTED:
        // Browser state is reduced in action creator because it uses an event
        return state

      default:
        return state
    }
  }
</script>
```

And so now I can bind

> statePath: 'route.current'

to any app-route component in my app. I can also use

> this.dispatch('redirected', '/some-path')

for redirection and standard anchor tags as the browser will sync with the state.

Comment: This was very helpful for this understanding central vs decentralized state management - and has helped me understand redux a little more to boot!

Answer (score 2):

I would create a non-visual polymer element that wraps an `app-route` and also implements the `polymer-redux` behavior and handles the interaction between `app-route` and the `redux` store.

Here is an example of a such an element for a wizard (with steps and analysis to be loaded):

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-route/app-location.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/app-route/app-route.html">

<dom-module id="my-router">
  <style>
  </style>
  <template>
      <app-location route="{{route}}"  id="location" use-hash-as-path></app-location>
      <app-route
            active="{{active}}"
            route="{{route}}"
            pattern="/:step/:id"
            data="{{page}}"
            tail="{{tail}}">
      </app-route>
  </template>
  <script>
    (function() {
      'use strict';
      Polymer({
        is: 'my-router',
        behaviors: [ ReduxBehavior ],
        properties: {
            page: {
                type:Object,
                value: function(){ return {};},
            },
            currentAnalysisId: {
                type:String,
                statePath: 'id',
            },
            currentStep: {
                type:String,
                statePath:'currentStep',
            },
            active:{
                type: Boolean,
                observer:'_onInValidRoute'
            }
        },
        observers: [
          '_changeRoute(page)',
          '_changeStepOrAnalysisId(currentStep,currentAnalysisId)',
        ],
        actions: {
             changeStep: function(step) {
                return {
                    type: 'CHANGE_CURRENT_STEP',
                    step,
                }
            },
            loadAnalysis: function(id,step)  {
                return {
                    type: 'LOAD_ANALYSIS',
                    id,
                    step,
                }
            },
        },
        _initialized : false,
        ready: function() {
            // required otherwise if navigating to a sub-route for the first time will be reset, by the localstorage initial redux state update
            this._initialized = true;
        },
        _changeRoute: function(page) {
            // required because otherwise
            this.debounce('route_update',()=>{
                let step = page.step;
                let id = page.id;

                if (id && this.getState().id !== id) {
                        ga('send', 'event', 'Analysis', 'load');
                        this.dispatch('loadAnalysis',id,step)
                }
                else if (this.getState().currentStep !== step) {
                    this.dispatch('changeStep',step);
                }
                ga('send', 'pageview');
            },1);
        },
        _changeStepOrAnalysisId: function(step, id) {
            if (!this._initialized) {
                return;
            }
            this.debounce('state_changed',()=>{
                if (this.page.step !== step || (this.page.id !== id && this.page.id !== '' && id !== null)) {
                    this.page = {step,id};
                }
            })
        },
        _onInValidRoute: function(valid) {
            if (!valid) {
                this.async(()=> {
                    this.$.location.set('route.path','/start/');
                })
            }
        },
      });
    })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Yeah, we're currently keeping our route state outside of Redux but will over time probably move in this direction. It does feel like we're manually recreating react-router-redux for Polymer, which maybe should already exist. But perhaps we should just be offering such a package ourselves.